# Substring a string value in string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq

I have an array of strings passed into a method:

```
private DataTable buildDataTableFromErrorPairs(string[] ErrorPairs)
{ ... }
```

I want to discern whether a string within the Array has a length greater than 150 characters & if so truncate it. I know there will only be a maximum of one string in the array with a length greater than 150. Tried some LINQ but obviously the original string is not changed:

```
var error = ( from e in ErrorPairs
              where e.Length > 150
              select e
            ).FirstOrDefault();

error = error.Substring(0, 100);
```

Tried this lambda which may be closer:

```
ErrorPairs = ErrorPairs.Select(s => s.Substring(0, 150)).ToArray();
```

Presumably I'll have to make a new array of strings after I've found & substringed the offending value? I usually work in WPF and use `List<T>` so don't have issues with removing & adding elements!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before all, if you want to know if there is at least one string greater then 150 in the array, you can use :

```
Boolean error = ErrorPairs.Any(e => e.Length > 150);
```

Then, for truncating the array, you have almost the answer with

```
ErrorPairs = ErrorPairs.Select(s => s.Substring(0, 150)).ToArray();
```

Just modify it with :

```
ErrorPairs = ErrorPairs.Select(s => s.Length > 150 ? s.Substring(0, 150) : s).ToArray();
```

That's all ;)

Comment: Does not take the "want to discern whether a string within the Array has a length greater than 150 characters" into account if that was a requirement.

Comment: ? acts as an if therefore stepping over the elements with a Length < 150, fantastic. Using forEach on an array doesn't actually change the original Array value. Presumably as the Array & its elements are immutable.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I edited and add the 'Any' query. But i'm not sure it's important to test it before truncate the array. Well, Hardgraf will see :)

Comment: @Xaruth: i also don't know it but OP has mentioned it. However, it would be nice to have an approach which does both in one query instead of enumerating the array twice. But it's not easy to provide a LINQ query which does both, similar to what the loop of Patrick does.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use LINQ you indeed have to create a new array since LINQ doesn't manipulate the input.

You could use a `for` loop instead:

```
bool foundTooLongError = false;
for (int i = 0; i < ErrorPairs.Length; i++)
{
    if (ErrorPairs[i].Length > 150)
    {
        ErrorPairs[i] = ErrorPairs[i].Substring(0, 150); // replace

        foundTooLongError = true;
        break; // only you are sure there is just one
    }
}
```

It will go through the entire list and replaces every offending line. Obviously, if you know it is just one, you can `break;` after you have found a string that is too long.

Comment: This is more efficient and has also the benefit that you know if there was a string greater than 150 characters since that seemed to be another requirement. You could simply assign `true` to a `bool` variable declared outside of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. You can use `Substring` inside your LINQ statement:

```
var error = (from e in ErrorPairs
             where e.Length > 150
             select e.Substring(0,150)).SingleOrDefault();
```

Also, since there's going to be a max of one match, you can use `SingleOrDefault()`.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the linq query syntax you propose. Needed to modify the original array, thanks @Grant Winney